# SwiftMailer Sends Mail Very Slowly

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am developing my php website on my own computer using WAMP Server. I am using the Swiftmailer to Send mail. It sends the Mail, But it works very slowly. It sends a single mail in about 8-12 seconds.
I am using the following code

```
   $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465, 'ssl');
    $transport->setUsername('xyzmail@gmail.com');
    $transport->setPassword('xyz12345');

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message->setTo("myownemail@gmail.com");
    $message->setSubject("Test Mail from News Page");
    $message->setFrom("xyzmail@gmail.com");
    $message->setBody("This is the Message Body");

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    if($mailer->send($message))
    {
        $output_msg = "Message Has been Sent Successfully!";
    }
    else
    {
        $output_msg = "Could Not Sent Message!";
    }
```

One Thing I mention here that I am not sending so much text in the message body, I am sending the same single line text, as I have used in the above example.

Why it is working so slow, Is there any problem on my part? or do I need to use any other mail sender tool?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if SwiftMail is the problem here.

Maybe server configurations does not allow to send e-mails faster. I had a problem like this when i was in a shared server.

Because sending email fast (i.e. every 0,5 secs) can overload the server so the server administrator have configured to send an email every 10 seconds.

Another reason could be for spam security.

Comment: How can I configure my server to send fast emails, if I have a VPS.